# Removing the number in front of a chapter

Tags: numbering, chapters, appendix

I want to remove the number in front of "Appendix" both in the TOC and in the text. The numbers of the other chapters should remain as they are. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{50 pt}%
{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \raggedright \normalfont
\bfseries\Huge\thechapter.\ #1
\par\nobreak\vspace{40 pt}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Intro}
\chapter{Main part}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\chapter{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote,

> I want to remove the number in front of "Appendix" both in the TOC and in the text.

You may achieve your objective by replacing

```
\chapter{Appendix}
```

with

```
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
```

The first instruction creates an unnumbered chapter-level header in the body of the document. The second writes the line `\contentsline {chapter}{Appendix}{5}` to the file `\jobname.toc`. This, in turn, influences the way the Table of Contents is typeset in the file `\jobname.pdf`.